# How to display different echos at php file in different html div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 files: html and php.
**HTML** file send variables to php via javascript.
**PHP** call perl file to 
1- process the data.
2- Then present the result in some `<table><tr><td>` .

**I want in html** 
1- display the processing statement in some div. //This done successfuly
2- display the result in another div. //How to do it?

```
javascript function
{
   var url = "file.php";
   var params = //some parameters;
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("ProcessingDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;     //This div show text about processing the data.

    document.getElementById("ResultDiv").innerHTML = //How to do this?
                }
        };
       xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
       xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       xhttp.send(params);
    }
```

some code of PHP file:

```
// some echo "processing data statement" here are displayed in ProcessingDiv

// statement which execute perl is here (the process takes 10 min and generate some files)

//I want below echos to displayed in ResultDiv

if(!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<p>No comparison meets cutoff criterion. </p>";
    }else {
    echo "<p><table border = 1 width=100% class='sortable'>";
    echo "<thead><tr><th>Query</th><th>Subject</th><th>Score</th</tr>  </thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    if($i == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td>$element[1]</td><td><input type='checkbox'>$target_name</td><td>$element[3]</td><td>$element[4]</td></tr>";
    }else{
                  //another echo
    }
```

**Is that possible to display php echos in two different div?**

**Note:**
My system behaviour:

1. The browser load the HTML file which takes input from the user and send form inputs to php file by click some button.
2. When the button is clicked It displays all the echos in php "before calling perl file" in ProcessingDiv. But after excuting the perl, How do display other echos in another div?

**Note**
I try using:

```
jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "blastresult.php",
        data:params,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#result').html(data);

        }
    });
```

And it do the same job. Presenting echoes before perl execution.

Hope you getting my point.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Your ajax request should already do this. If your page reloads - then ajax not working propperly. Start with opening developers' console in browser and check for errors there.

Comment: Check if the ajax request is success/correct and returning the response. This can be seen in the browser console.

Comment: It do that. It displays all the echos in php "before calling perl file" in my div. But after excuting the perl, it does not show the other echos.

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy my ajax request is working

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Please could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to display php echo on your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function displayOutput()
{
    var dataString = "name=abc&gender=male";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#myDiv').html(data);

        }
    });

}

</script>
```

Comment: Where to put the parameters? I want to send some parameters of the form to the php.

Comment: I have updated my code. You can set parameter in function also e.g: displayOutput(someValue);

Comment: Can I put this: var params = "querySeq="+querySeq+"&program="+program;

Comment: Yes sure. dataString ="querySeq="+querySeq+"&program="+program;

Comment: I try it. It does not workin! My hhtp request in my post is works fine but stop at calling perl.

Comment: @ Neeraj Kumar the error in web console: $.ajax is not a function.

Comment: Make sure you load jquery on your html page:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I get an error in my platform when i include the lib. when i remove it, the error remove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104475/discussion-between-reem-and-neeraj-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by seplit the response text:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
    var parts = xhttp.responseText.split("--seperator---");
    document.getElementById("ProcessingDiv").innerHTML = parts[0];
    document.getElementById("ResultDiv").innerHTML = parts[1];
                }
```

Thanks everyone.